# setting nproc in /etc/security/limit.conf prevents ssh login

Tags: linux, ssh, ulimit

I am trying to use **/etc/security/limit.conf** on Linux (Debian) to limit the number of processes per user.

for starters, I tried to limit my own user processes by adding this to /etc/security/limit.conf:

```
omry hard nproc 100
```

this locked my user out of ssh. I could open new processes (verified with **su omry**), but could not log into ssh with that user : sshd reported this in it's log:

> fatal: setreuid 1000: Resource temporarily unavailable

also, I am certain my user is not running anything near 100 processes (actually 6). what can be the reason for this?

Comment: noproc not nproc

Did you read the man page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now know that Java threads also count as processes.
It's likely that I had a Java server that used that many threads.